# How to cite papers in my statement of purpose?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose, interview

How to cite papers in my statement of purpose? The interview panel has asked me to cite the papers from which I have taken a general idea about my statement of purpose. Kindly guide me through the process?

Comment: Is your question on how to cite papers in general or what would be an appropriate format for doing it in a statement of purpose?

Comment: Exactly the same way you would cite papers in any other document.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask them to clarify the citation format (e.g. [Wikipedia offers some examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation)), or you can simply pick one of the listed options of systems or styles available.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the right way to do. But this is what I did to highlight mine:
Google search this "sarnath kannan HCL site:www.altera.com OR site:ieeexplore.ieee.org" will give you all my papers.
So, I just linked like [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?dcr=0&ei=yJZpWrWsEsjRvgSbmYCIBg&q=sarnath%20kannan%20HCL%20site%3Awww.altera.com%20OR%20site%3Aieeexplore.ieee.org&oq=sarnath%20kannan%20HCL%20site%3Awww.altera.com%20OR%20site%3Aieeexplore.ieee.org&gs_l=psy-ab.3...27929.28204.0.28568.3.3.0.0.0.0.79.226.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.cz40rrmrbnM)
Hope this helped! I am yet to submit my SOP. So, if this is a bad idea, Please alert me.